# Fast-render not working with Flow-router

Tags: javascript, performance, meteor, flow-router

I'm trying to add [fast-rendering](https://github.com/kadirahq/fast-render) into my current app, which uses [flow-router](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#fast-render).

I've imported the `router.js` in both `client` as well as `server`, and added the `subscriptions()` function to my route definition, like so:

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  name: 'Main',
  subscriptions() {
    this.register('allTeams', Meteor.subscribe('allTeams'));
  },
  action() {
    mount(Basic, { content: <App /> });
  },
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work as the initial HTML loaded doesn't seem to include the initial load data

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/merged-stylesheets.css?hash=66297db7ce0861d8515cbc9745f889f7a44afb3e">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
  <title>Clicky!</title>

</head>
<body>



<script type="text/javascript">__meteor_runtime_config__ = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent("%7B%22meteorRelease%22%3A%22METEOR%401.5.1%22%2C%22meteorEnv%22%3A%7B%22NODE_ENV%22%3A%22development%22%2C%22TEST_METADATA%22%3A%22%7B%7D%22%7D%2C%22PUBLIC_SETTINGS%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22ROOT_URL%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F%22%2C%22ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX%22%3A%22%22%2C%22appId%22%3A%2211tfp6ttdhgdpo3wzz4%22%2C%22autoupdateVersion%22%3A%22d3ada84377c112891c944017fc4fb1996ab2f202%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionRefreshable%22%3A%2214dfede7f12a46ade065ec58219591137c679eab%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionCordova%22%3A%22none%22%7D"));</script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/underscore.js?hash=cde485f60699ff9aced3305f70189e39c665183c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteor.js?hash=814eae5b938a9a89ce7cf9174c98be4982f953d8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteor-base.js?hash=a4d07a6b394e56bbe6ccc773c95e7cdb3434960d"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mobile-experience.js?hash=8ded3e69a3e367f321ab9a2b52e3ecdd2661a365"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/babel-compiler.js?hash=a9546d4e245cfe40b406e08d40bf106241f01683"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ecmascript.js?hash=370a8752194bcf73be7fffa3635715d0fbf7853d"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/base64.js?hash=0053489bb30bb5c0e3545df151f83e41150344b0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ejson.js?hash=0f17ced99d522d48cd8f8b2139167fd06babd969"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/id-map.js?hash=c7aea8dfa2bf46ff2ae0aa6c6cf09e36abc61d07"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ordered-dict.js?hash=bacdd1852075630a01f7de783e5e8e8aa8541cdc"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/modules.js?hash=f54f0a303135090c544bc624c0d33aa81f2519e3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ecmascript-runtime.js?hash=ed0d1c9624ff822ac7a673101e02acc5a1471a22"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/es5-shim.js?hash=4187fffd3f43294b6953a57a6a17c24fbf2af5d2"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/promise.js?hash=68cae2c639c7a67d8dbe7d0ec4dbc81aefc182aa"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/babel-runtime.js?hash=19ef5d5ba37e9a2d052fbaadafbe5079845d8f26"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ecmascript-runtime-client.js?hash=ebe5054265cd34dd320c7a8cc00c62601ba9f58b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/random.js?hash=49bdca10b45b36115e6aa1acbc9dd294091ea928"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mongo-id.js?hash=345d169d517353f8146292b4abd24061721f8b26"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/diff-sequence.js?hash=15014d7b1e11c05111a386992e684ab1d3cc4158"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/geojson-utils.js?hash=401d570cf4ab9b4470b0a68dfab45f3321d9fceb"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/minimongo.js?hash=4f5c421ee64a333e2a96f515d4287fc153ec9252"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/check.js?hash=a2540f962c925251e9ed815a46332e7712760474"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/retry.js?hash=1e409617b538ff3e2b0238b15e45b3380c51a224"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp-common.js?hash=83c6dba3051ec76b5c1cd85d39357f0f501add98"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reload.js?hash=02487cd11db41d01f7837ad146e4680a9e8d2e12"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=14d966b7972bd95a1f7015fec9ac340f10508a44"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp.js?hash=25dc3f428447c81620c91c4245dbc6e4f7d32fb7"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp-server.js?hash=1beefbc7bd033ea687e7ab8fbd5694df072662af"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/allow-deny.js?hash=92ac887172b3b2c2522bf4c9a634d90247b338d4"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mongo.js?hash=e92cf37034f2703254bf91c2d4a148271b91342c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/blaze-html-templates.js?hash=6e8335ce66460e45f00da73c7497654c5e26e236"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reactive-var.js?hash=ec712fa3ae588c4a1e7017f0bb4507c725391225"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/standard-minifier-css.js?hash=cfe82682f4394d3ffc6335555c1f9f3f73294507"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/standard-minifier-js.js?hash=041bab58c8a89172eaab795deb5d96e38b64ec37"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/shell-server.js?hash=6ff1313e4bf7618e577eb2604a580b2ea9b7631f"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reactive-dict.js?hash=6fb8f893720a4d179c0db118d90d5e7eef5153d6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/jquery.js?hash=0c5fac3e4b18ec685e561deac3634fb49bc807e5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteorhacks_inject-data.js?hash=4761d8bfeaaee92da0178e51bd787e28865b70a7"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/chuangbo_cookie.js?hash=678eb757a3052e339582a74e75c3cd3cffe8a40f"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/deps.js?hash=7313f5a2685c6c2c673c78c15c8ce86ff59ab0c9"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp-rate-limiter.js?hash=457af847f89d207a6ca630c56f06d2a3af3a414c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/localstorage.js?hash=b8f7913d89016e62d42164380fabfc1366797d36"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/callback-hook.js?hash=e15ed8aa52e7c647efd9f4854e8a0fe4e40808fc"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/observe-sequence.js?hash=8fe58036c6ba00c458f54c360a21fd0e41fb7ee0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/htmljs.js?hash=1ac878018eee6c53ed1375dc7ee75fc6865666ae"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/accounts-base.js?hash=6a4c856fbcc54a9e0a584a6e104ef7d16b8ec5f6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteorhacks_fast-render.js?hash=543e29057cacad25a0d6f18583d56805b77133e5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/kadira_flow-router.js?hash=310d7cd0f453b68e1f11fa81928610fb20813e66"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/tmeasday_check-npm-versions.js?hash=dc479d10bd43094d77b8fa694b90aea8d3404e27"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/react-meteor-data.js?hash=ce32adc2cecffb9535e28d205cc53eef5ae36327"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/aldeed_simple-schema.js?hash=13e803ef04b6685a7577083e5871767a498b6351"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/raix_eventemitter.js?hash=b009bf66474c7942360d5e2bba2398ec847d81dc"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/aldeed_collection2-core.js?hash=cd76f0a8f289f873c33e0896e9a86201e64a47d1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/aldeed_schema-index.js?hash=2ca1861c8f7de7459aa47835657b11b4e560c8e7"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/aldeed_schema-deny.js?hash=c46f0998a459ed45c0c557fcb85c31b85c40e7d4"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/aldeed_collection2.js?hash=2a40052f92753d39451338b55e6d318a4bf46a3b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/fourseven_scss.js?hash=080f9a0a149e205f9ebc6171dc54f856dba838ab"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/materialize_materialize.js?hash=cad3a0b9203285245063c348bd2e2aed7f7c9573"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/webapp.js?hash=21a471b5e10ef4f65b9925eaf8d227797c060a10"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/livedata.js?hash=7cf1831a60b48e304b054aee1ae0f7e38ff35d09"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/dynamic-import.js?hash=d3e0fe1c9fb2d37129ef347d1ee905ade2691f6c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/hot-code-push.js?hash=2e864a0bdd0d5f686115099f8c48eb6c866b5b14"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/spacebars.js?hash=ebf9381e7fc625d41acb0df14995b7614360858a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/templating-compiler.js?hash=a71883cdec50e95ca135291415990753ed6d57fc"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/templating-runtime.js?hash=c18de19afda6e9f0db7faf3d4382a4c953cabe18"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/templating.js?hash=c2cf38de06efb47f67affb2dff9320e5eef33893"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/launch-screen.js?hash=2f56943306c7e900ed9f4d894b87f534ebffeaeb"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ui.js?hash=039c55a98376abd03d9d8cd4100895861b897643"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/autoupdate.js?hash=1fd9cf3472adaa6887170d88ab5ea1ddabf695fa"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/global-imports.js?hash=aefba5f001df7c63d154d4128a2752b411556608"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js?hash=965d954fd523022df05f94b1167321ba34799b8e"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mdg_validation-error.js?hash=9df8c3f9376af1b92879fee50b9a91c60e2cfaf2"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/service-configuration.js?hash=42ac9ae8eb44f3e73762f9cb0003410397021984"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps, you're using `appcache` package? Currently FastRender does not support simultaneous usage with appcache package.

Comment: @Styx I don't think so, it isn't in my packages list

Comment: The `appcache` is a part of Webapp, not 3rd party package. Check whether your code contains something like `Meteor.AppCache.config(...)` or not.

Comment: No, my app doesn't contain `Meteor.AppCache.config(...)` either

Comment: Well then, let's see your `allTeams` publication :)

Comment: It's annoyingly simple :)

`Meteor.publish('allTeams', function () {
  return Teams.find();
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed! Found a forked repo with a fix

`meteor add staringatlights:fast-render`

instead of

`meteor add meteorhacks:fast-render`